# CoreData Model Objects for API

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, model

I am using CoreData in my application. I want to abstract out all the CoreData related stuff as an API so that the consume can use the API instead of directly using CoreData and its generated model objects. CoreData generates the managed objects model as following

```
@interface Person : NSManagedObject

@end
```

I want to define my API for example MyAPI and it has a function called as

```
createPerson:(Person*)p;
```

So the consumer of this createPerson API needs to create a Person data object (like POJO in java world) and invoke this API. But I cannot create Person object using

```
Person *p = [Person alloc] init]
```

because the designated initializer for this Person model created by CoreData does not allow this type of creation.

So should I define corresponding user facing data object may be PersonDO and this API should take that instead to carry the data into the API implementation?

Is my approach right? Any expert advise if design the API this way is a good design pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use CoreData without dealing with Managed Object Context. You **MUST** get the person from the context and save it in the context. If you don't want your customer to deal with that, and you don't use different threads in your app,you could create a api,that will call your appdelegate's Managed Object Context, and all the user will need to do is just to call that method.

For example,you could use automaticly generated by Core Data methods  to make your API like that:

```
+ (Person *)newPersonWithAttributes:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    // Call the designated initializer, but customer
    // doesn't need to think about managed object context
    return [Person initPesonWithAttributes:userInfo 
                    inManagedObjectContext:[[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] managedObjectContext]];
}
```

Comment: Looks like that is supposed to be a class method.  Replace '-' with '+'.

Comment: Also, there needs to be lots of other stuff... not practical unless you add categories on NSManagedObject so that "save" is called on the context, in addition to other things.

Comment: Yes,it should be added to categoey,both wit save,delete,and all the other stuff

Answer (score 1):

You need lots of stuff to abstract that out.  RestKit provides mechanisms to do that.  Lighter weight would be InnerBand (See tutorial [InnerBand CoreData](http://raptureinvenice.com/innerband-2/)) - though it does not automatically determine threads/queues for multi-threads.

However, it is a very simple API, and should give you most of what you want.